# I am facing an error "This command is required to run from within an SFDX project" while using "sfdx force:source:push" command

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

This code i need to deploy in org

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>
            lightning__AppPage
        </target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

This is the code

Answer (score 0):

It's different commands.

For old school metadata API deployments and package.xml you're supposed to use exactly that, "mdapi:deploy" and "mdapi:retrieve" commands. You can run them against any org, they'll overwrite the files without asking / detecting conflicts etc etc. It's also only way to promote code to partial copy, full copy and production.

If you have a source-tracked org (a scratch org or developer sandbox with devhub and tracking enabled) you can use "source:push", "source:pull". They will check for conflicts and they will also "magically" know what changed server-side. Life is too short for hand-crafting the package.xml. You want to add a field or build a report and have 1-click download to local XML files - get familiar with source tracking. (It's never "just a field". Field, page layout, profiles/permsets, maybe listview, maybe report types..
Screw adding it all to package manually).

Source-tracked changes can't be pushed straight to prod, you need to convert them to old mdapi format. There's a command for that and it produces package.xml for you.